# How to source nushell scripts to another

Tags: nushell

I have two nu files in the same directory.

#### printer.nu

```
#!/bin/nu
module printer {
    export def print [] {
        echo '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>'
    }
}
```

#### run.nu

```
#!/bin/nu

source printer.nu

def main [] {
    use printer print
    print
}
```

When the `./run.nu` is ran from the same directory they are in, script runs successfully. However, from any other location, it throws an error.

```
Error: nu::parser::sourced_file_not_found (link)

  × File not found
   ╭─[test/test.nu:2:1]
 2 │ 
 3 │ source printer.nu
   ·        ────┬─────
   ·            ╰── File not found: printer.nu
 4 │ 
   ╰────
  help: sourced files need to be available before your script is run
```

Comment: Add absolute path to `printer.nu`

Comment: I guess `nushell` should allow searching included/sourced files from a list of PATH in a variable.

Comment: There is `$env.NU_LIB_DIRS` in `env.nu` for that (I hope I remember the name correctly, only on the phone)